# Creating folder on ftp if does not exist

Tags: iphone, ftp

I am interested to find out how to perform FTP asynchronously..

I am calling one method from the main view and then the main view navigates to some other view. Now the method that is called should perform the ftp process in the background without any issue.

I am not able to achieve this: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/41143-beginnersquestion-simpleftp-example.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/URLGetController_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-URLGetController_h-DontLinkElementID_15

I have referenced this but is there any other way to do the FTP process?

I have files in a queue which are ftp one after the other in the async method.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/ is a great example of doing all sorts of FTP things with the iPhone.

Comment: I want to create a particular folder and then have the file in that folder like ftp://someloction/Folder/filename

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry i am able to assist with your code but i can help with the ftp command side of things, if would recommend to try and changing into the directory that you are looking for with using CWD <\dirname> and look for the response: 550 <\dirname>: No such file or directory.

When you have recieved this response you will then be able to create the directory with using the command of MKD <\dirname> to create a directory.

Hope this helps ..

Comment: I want to achieve it programatically.

Comment: Selwyn, if you can connect and pro-grammaticality send commands to the ftp using the SimpleFTPSample as posted by lef2 above, I have given you the commands to use to achieve that. As I said in my reply, I am unable to assist with the code, but using what lef2 provided above and my post i am sure that you can figure it out. In short, we can assist, but not do your job for you :D